# iOS - core animation -- view shifts when not expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

`_plank` is an UIImageView initialized through interfacebuilder.

I am using the following:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
 animations:^{
     _plank.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
     _plank.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(_plank.transform, 1);
 }
 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

 }];
```

What ends up happening is the UIImageView moves randomly across the screen, but rotates in the needed way. What should I do to stop it from moving across the screen?

Comment: Why are you changing the anchor point in the first place?

Comment: I tested code without changing the anchor point and it still behaves the same way. I thought that redefining the anchor point would help.

Comment: Are you 1) using Auto Layout? 2) Changing the frame or transform elsewhere? 3) Relying on the frame after the transform has been set?

Comment: Autolayout was the problem. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to turn off autolayout to work. Credits to @David Rönnqvist